# Shape of the limiting polygon

Tags: geometry

Please look at the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859432/area-of-the-limiting-polygon?rq=1). What is the shape of the polygon at the end?

Start with an equilateral triangle with unit area. Trisect each of the sides and then cut-off the corners. In this case, we get a regular hexagon - see the picture below. Next, trisect each of the sides of the hexagon and cut-off the corners. This will give a dodecagon, but not a regular one.

Continue this process ad infinitum.

What is the SHAPE of the limiting "polygon"?

Not sure but I don't think it's going to be a circle

Comment: Hmmmm..  I'm pretty sure that one thing we can be certain of is that the midpoint of each generated segment remains forever.  That might help.

Comment: Yes, that does remain forever

Comment: Any idea to find out?

Answer (score 2):

The limiting polygon appears to be rather nondescript, though it's clearly not a circle.

I wrote a program using Sage. It starts with an ordered list of the vertices of the equilateral triangle. On each iteration it creates a new list, replacing the vertices in the list with new vertices at the points $1/3$ and $2/3$ of the way along each edge.

The plot below is after $12$ iterations. At this point the polygon has $3\times 2^{12}=12288$ sides. The initial equilateral triangle is shown for reference.

The number of sides far exceeds the image resolution so this should be a good approximation to the limiting polygon. Note that I manually scaled the original plot to get the aspect ratio close to $1:1$ in the final image.

[image]